# Haskell Power Set Function

Tags: haskell, powerset

I get an error:

```
working.hs:186:25: error:
* Couldn't match expected type: Set (Set a)
              with actual type: [[a]]
* In the expression:
    union (map (insert x) (powerSet s)) (powerSet s)
  In an equation for `powerSet':
      powerSet (Node x s)
        = union (map (insert x) (powerSet s)) (powerSet s)
* Relevant bindings include
    s :: Set a (bound at working.hs:186:20)
    x :: a (bound at working.hs:186:18)

working.hs:186:48: error:
* Couldn't match expected type: [[a]]
              with actual type: Set (Set a)
* In the second argument of `map', namely `(powerSet s)'
  In the first argument of `union', namely
    `(map (insert x) (powerSet s))'
  In the expression: union (map (insert x) (powerSet s)) (powerSet s)
* Relevant bindings include
    s :: Set a (bound at working.hs:186:20)
    x :: a (bound at working.hs:186:18)

working.hs:186:62: error:
* Couldn't match expected type: [[a]]
              with actual type: Set (Set a)
* In the second argument of `union', namely `(powerSet s)'
  In the expression: union (map (insert x) (powerSet s)) (powerSet s)
  In an equation for `powerSet':
      powerSet (Node x s)
        = union (map (insert x) (powerSet s)) (powerSet s)
* Relevant bindings include
    s :: Set a (bound at working.hs:186:20)
    x :: a (bound at working.hs:186:18)

Failed, no modules loaded.
```

My function is:

```
powerSet :: Set a -> Set (Set a)
powerSet EmptyS = singleton EmptyS
powerSet (Node x s) = union (map (insert x) (powerSet s)) (powerSet s)
```

Why do I get the error?

Comment: What do you think the type of `map` is?  And what is the type of `insert`?

Comment: It looks like you are mixing functions that operate of lists with functions that operate on sets. Your `powerSet` function code looks promising, but you need set versions of `map` and other helper functions for that to work.

Comment: Can you share the `data` definition of `Set` together with implementations for `union`, `insert`, etc.?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem
I have got:

`insert :: (Ord a) => a -> Set a -> Set a

   insert x EmptyS = Node x EmptyS

   insert x (Node y s)

       | x == y = Node y s

       | otherwise = Node y (insert x s)`



  `union :: (Ord a) => Set a -> Set a -> Set a
   union EmptyS s2 = s2
   union s1 EmptyS = s1
   union s1 s2 = foldr insertSet s1 (toList s2)`

Otherwise I imported the toList and fromList from Data Set

Comment: Hmm there are `EmptyS` and `Node`, where do they come from? They are not in `Data.Set`. Is this your own `Set`? You need to post a [mre]. "Otherwise I imported the toList and fromList from Data Set" If you have your own `Set` you can't do that.

Comment: `data Set a = EmptyS | Node a (Set a)
       deriving (Show)`

Comment: `toList :: Ord a => Set a -> [a]
   toList EmptyS = []
   toList (Node x s) = isort (x : toList s)`---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
   `isort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
   isort [] = []
   isort (x:xs) =
       let smallerSorted = isort [a | a <- xs, a <= x]  
           biggerSorted = isort [a | a <- xs, a > x]  
       in  smallerSorted ++[x]++ biggerSorted` 
   --------
   fromList :: Ord a => [a] -> Set a
   fromList [] = EmptyS
   fromList (x:xs) = Node x (fromList (filter (/= x) xs))

Comment: Please [edit] your question with relevant information

Answer (score 1):

As other contributors have mentioned in the comments to the question, `map` only works on lists.  To "map" `insert x` over `powerSet s`, you would have to create a functor instance for the `Set` type, then use `fmap` instead.

```
instance Functor Set where
    fmap f EmptyS      = EmptyS
    fmap f (Node x s') = Node (f x) (fmap f s')
```

Then you would have:

```
powerSet :: Ord a => Set a -> Set (Set a)
powerSet EmptyS = singleton EmptyS
powerSet (Node x s') = union (fmap (insert x) (powerSet s')) (powerSet s')
```

I did not see your code for `singleton`, so I will include mine for completeness.

```
singleton :: Ord a => a -> Set a
singleton x = Node x EmptyS
```

I notice your type signature for `powerSet` does not include the `Ord a` constraint.  You will need this since `insert` requires `Ord a`.  Then in order to use it on sets themselves you will also have to define instances of `Ord` and `Eq` for `Set a`.  This is fairly straightforward:

```
instance (Ord a) => Eq (Set a) where
  (==) EmptyS EmptyS = True
  (==) EmptyS _      = False
  (==) _ EmptyS      = False
  (==) s0 s1         = (toList s0) == (toList s1)

instance (Ord a) => Ord (Set a) where
  compare s0 s1 = compare (toList s0) (toList s1)
```

Comment: The `Ord a` constraint makes me wonder if the set representation is supposed to be sorted, or if there's some other non trivial invariant. In that case, your functor instance might break that invariant. (Hard to tell...)